# Shared Resources Between PHP Children 'Threads'

Tags: php, multithreading, process, resources, scope

I have a PHP script that spawns two child processes (pcntl_fork()) which each call methods of a single class instance (the names of the classes and methods and their functionality are simplified for easier explanation).

```
    class Main_Class 
    {

     public $array = array();

     public function push($value) {
      $this->array[] = $value;
     }
     public function pop() {
      return array_shift($this->array);
     }
    }

    $pc = new Thread_Creator();
    $main_class = new Main_Class();

    $pc->fork(array($main_class, 'push'), 1);
    $pc->fork(array($main_class, 'pop'), 1);

    The fork method is executed like so: call_user_func($main_class, 'pushToArray')
```

I intended these processes to share the same resources (one process pushes information into a public class variable of type array while one pops from it). Currently, both process run concurrently but only one seems to have access to the class variable $array.

Are shared resources possible between separate PIDs?

Any suggestions for solving this issue? (I would like to keep the processes separate as I intend to run them at different intervals)

If you need any more info or code snippets let me know

Comment: If you want to share resources between two (child) processes, you use shared memory. Check `shm_` functions. The two processes cannot see each other's `$this->array`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Must have missed this page previous to asking the question: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Managing-Standalone-Scripts-in-PHP/1/. I'll let you know how it works

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use shared memory to accomplish the task. For those interested, take a look here:

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/05/13/shared_memory.html?page=2

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php